# what is $\cos(2^k\cos^{-1}(x))$?

Tags: trigonometry

For $\cos(2\cos^{-1}(x))$ we can say it is equal to $2\cos^2(\cos^{-1}(x))-1$ which is $2x^2-1$ but for $\cos(2^k\cos^{-1}(x))$ is there any way to simplify ?
I have tried to use the double angle Cosine for multiple times, but I don't think this is going to work !

Comment: Actually, it should be $2x^2-1$.

Comment: Here's a nice graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/78iajwnzxe

Answer (score 3):

These are the $2^k$th [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the first kind. The $n$th Chebyshev polynomial can be written as:

$$T_n(x)=\cos(n\arccos x)), x\in [-1,1]$$

You can easily show that:

$$T_{2n}(x)=2T_n^2(x) -1$$

so you can compute $T_{2^k}(x)$ recursively.

You can also see it as:

$$T_{2^k}(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{2^{k-1}} \binom{2^k}{2j}(x^2-1)^jx^{2^k-2j}$$

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are called the Chebyshev Polynomials.  Here is a [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#First_kind).

Much more to read at the link, but there is a recurrence relation for these:
$$\cos(nx)=2\cos(x)\cos[(n–1)x]–\cos[(n – 2)x].$$
Applying this formula to your expression, we have
$$\cos(2^k\arccos x)=2\cos(\arccos x)\cos[(2^k–1)\arccos x]–\cos[2^k-2\arccos x].$$
So $\cos(2^k\arccos x)=T_{2^k}(x),$ where $T_n(x)$ is the $n$th Chebyshev Polynomial of the first kind.